# @media for drop down menu - show menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

I want to have my site responsive to different screen sizes.  At the moment I am testing my site at a width of 765px (and lower). What I would like to happen is for the menu to appear when I click the three bars, but nothing happens. No menu appears, just the 'brand name'.

I am using the bootstrap navigation for my menu.

This is a screenshot of the page (edited):
[image]

The Jquery code: - external file

```
@media screen and (min-width: 280px) and (max-width: 765px){
/* code goes here */
    .primary {
        color: orange !important;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
```

The color change is for testing sizes.

The HTML: - navigation only

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-header">
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><span class="primary">#</span></a>
            </div>
             <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="privacy.php">Privacy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="terms.php">Terms</a></li>
                    <li><a href="copy.php">Copyright</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- navbar collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
```

What have I missed?
How I can I solve my issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: "what have I missed?" -> That code is CSS, not jQuery!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the reasons would be messing up the order of `jQuery` and `bootstrap.js`. Bootstrap requires jQuery in order to run some events. So make sure your `jquery` script is before `bootstrap.min.js` or `bootstrap.js`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-header">
             <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><span class="primary">#</span></a>
            </div>
             <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                 <li class="active"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a href="privacy.php">Privacy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="terms.php">Terms</a></li>
                    <li><a href="copy.php">Copyright</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- navbar collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.